# Convert JSON to CSV using Microsoft Flow

Tags: json, csv, power-automate

I am trying to parse JSON data from an API into Flow, convert it into a CSV and then output the CSV to my Google Drive.

The API I am trying to work with is located here:

https://www.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=BNBBTC&interval=1h&limit=24

Is this possible using Microsoft flow? I have tried various things without much success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful [https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/flow/data-operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/flow/data-operations)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it is possible. What have you tried so far?

First you have to get the response body. Then extract the "meat" from each element, which has to be done with flow expressions "body(response_body)[0]" - depending on format. Then feed all these data parts to a newly created excel file.